# Why my code works in OnCreate but not in OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, oncreate, onitemclicklistener

I´ve made and app that shows a calendar and when i click in a day, i want to show a `ListView` customize.

My problem is that when i used the code in the `OnCreate`, it works, but when i used it in `OnItemClickListener` of the calendar it doesn´t do anything.

Here it´s my code. I appreciate your work and help

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(imagesCharacter[i], imagesAnime[i], characters[i], animes[i]);

        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    CustomListViewAdapter myAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),       R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item" + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

    });
```

If you ask, i do the findViewById of the ListView when i run the app.

SOLUTION:

I found the problem and now it works.

The problem was that the ListView was a child of a LinearLayout and always got or Null when i did the findViewById, or something else that didn´t work.

So i delete de Layout and when i did my findViewById worked.

Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: Just remove this line toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0); and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getApplicationContext()` (which should be avoided when possible) use `YourActivityName.this`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to the Activity's context by doing:

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    mContext = this;
}
```

then pass the context reference to your `OnItemClickListener` like:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item" + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       // Other codes here. 
    }
});
```